# mysql utf8 character problem

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, character-encoding

I set all character set as "utf8" in pages, I set all collation (also fields collation) as `utf8_general_ci` in database, and I add this code in `connect.php`

```
mysql_set_charset('utf8',$connect);
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
```

Although everything is utf, when i run this query:

`"SELECT * FROM titles WHERE title='toruń'"`

Result: it returns "`toruń`" and "`torun`" which's are different words.

So what do you think?
What is the problem?

Thanks!

EDIT:

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `titles`
 (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `title` (`title`),

) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=37 ;

Comment: can you test it in phpmyadmin or the mysql command line

Comment: dump the table schema and add it to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the collation you have chosen is designed to ignore that particular accent (and, most likely, accents in general).

If you expect to be storing a particular language, rather than a number of different languages, try using `utf8_(language)_ci` (if that language is not present, there might be another language which is similar to yours). Otherwise, you could try `utf8_unicode_ci`, which uses the Unicode Collation Algorithm, but I'm not sure if that one makes this distinction.

You can also use `utf8_bin`, which is guaranteed to consider them different, but that comes at the expense of losing case insensitivity, which is most likely worse.

Having said that, this is not necessarily a bad thing: by ignoring the accents, the search will be more flexible, and easier to use for people who are unable to type a specific character.

Comment: i'm working on a polish website, but it's not local. yes maybe in search query it's good, but in inserting that's so bad. because my pseudo code is like "if(!exist_in_table('torun')) then create_row("torun").

Answer (score 0):

try using [utf8_encode](http://ch2.php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php).

Answer (score 0):

you want utf8_bin, *_ci is case insensitive, so accents are treated as the regular letter

Comment: when I change the collation of 'title' filed as utf8_polish_ci, have to i change the collation for all tables or just fields.